# Changing Inside Header Element - Font Color

Tags: css

I am currently working on creating an accordion-style element and am having trouble changing the font-color in the clicked element to `white`. Can anyone help in changing my font color instead of black to white?

http://jsfiddle.net/rgs6vLub/13/

CSS:

```
.accordion h4 { padding-left: .5em; padding-bottom: .5em; color: white; }
                .accordion, .accordion * {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }
        .accordion {
            background-color: #456db5;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 10px 0;
        }
        .accordion dt {
            padding: 0.5em;
            background-color: white;
            cursor:pointer;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #8fcde5;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: black;
        }
        .accordion dt:hover {
            color: black;
        }
        .accordion .on {
            background-color: #456db5;
            cursor:default;
        }

        .accordion dt .on { color: white; }

        .accordion dt, .accordion .on:hover {
            color:black;
        }
        .accordion dd {
            padding-left: 1em;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding-right: 0.5em;
            background-color: white;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        /* NOTE:
         Do not apply top/bottom padding or margin to the accordion content,
         as its affects to the box model will cause the animation to be choppy.
         Instead, apply vertical spacing to the content elements.
         */
        .accordion dd p {
            padding-top:.5em;
            padding-bottom:.5em;
        }
        .accordion dt:last-of-type{
            border-bottom:none;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your .on style to be `color:white !important;` instead of `color:white`

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
.accordion .on {
      color: #fff !important;
    }
```